# How do I allow the HTML form element and HTML5 elements and attributes when using HTMLPurifier?

Tags: html, htmlpurifier

what code do I need to add inorder to allow the form element and HTML5 when using htmlpurifier?

Answer (score 1):

Just reed this http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-customize.html